# How to force AddThis dropdown to the left?

Tags: javascript, css, addthis

I'm using AddThis (http://www.addthis.com/) on one of my sites, and it's working just fine. But I've noticed that the dropdown box will always open to the right side, if there's room enough to the right in the browser window. If there's not enough space to the right, the dropdown will open to the left side.

But I'd very much like the dropdown box to open to the left side all the time. Also if there's enough space to the right.

But I simply can't get this to work.

My AddThis widget works just like on this site: http://home.dk/
You can see the small button ("Del siden") in the right side next to the print and e-mail buttons.

As you can see the box opens to the right if the browser windows is wide enough. But try to make the browser window smaller  so there's not enough room for the drop down. Then it will open to the left.

How can I force the dropdown box to open to the left all the time?

Thanks you very much in advance folks...

Best regards,
Kim

Answer (score 0):

Read: http://www.addthis.com/help/client-api#configuration-ui

Try to use `ui_offset_left` and set a negative offset to the left so it positions it. You also have `ui_hover_direction` but not sure if that will accept a left value.

Comment: Tried both of those options, but none of them solves my problem. If I set some offset, then the bex will be moved to much to the left when the browwser window is not very wide. And the hover_direction only works for forcing the dropdown above or below the button itself.